# Accessing old model attribute from Mongoose middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a `Category` model which it's only property is `name`.

There is also a `SubCategory` model which has a `name` and a `category` string field containing the name of it's `Category` model.

When a `Category` model's `name` changes, each `SubCategory` pointing to that category should update it's `category` field to match the new name.

I'm currently implementing this directly on the route handler by getting all `SubCategories` that points to a certain category, iterating trough them and updating it's category field.

I want to implement this logic in the model, where it should belong.

I created a pre middleware on `Category` model,

```
CategorySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  console.log('Saving ' + this.name);
  next();
});
```

The route handler in charge of the `PUT` request saves the model with an updated name like this:

```
...
parentCategory.name = requestedName;
parentCategory.validate(function(validationError) {          
  if (validationError) {
    return res.send(response.BAD_REQUEST); 
  }     
  parentCategory.save(function(saveError) {       
    if(saveError) {
      return res.send(response.SERVER_ERROR);        
    }
  });
});
...
```

However I get printed the **NEW** name, so I cant iterate trought it's subcategories as I only have access to the new name.

I'm not sure how am I supposed to pass both the old and the new name to the middleware to do the stuff there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to access the old value by quering to the Category model like this:

```
CategorySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var that = this;
    var updateEachSubCategory = function(subcategory) {
    subcategory.category = that.name;
    subcategory.save(function(saveError) {
      if(saveError) {
        console.log(saveError);
        return 1;                    
      }
    });
  };
    var updateChildrenCategoryField = function(err, subCategoriesArray) {
        solange.asyncFor(subCategoriesArray, updateEachSubCategory);   
    };
    var findChildren = function(categorySearchError, categoryFound) {
        if(!categorySearchError) {
            mongoose.models["SubCategory"].find({ category: categoryFound.name }, updateChildrenCategoryField);
        }
    };
    mongoose.models["Category"].findOne({ _id: this._id }, findChildren);
    next();
});
```

As this is a **pre** save middleware, the new name is not saved yet so we have access to it by quering the model.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to backup attribute values in post init middleware

```
schema.post('init', function(model) {
  model.oldValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model));
}
```

Than we can access those attributes in any other middleware, e.g. `this.someAttr === this.oldValues.someAttr` before attribute modification.

I wrote a [gist to check it](https://gist.github.com/oshybystyi/ad98f3963ab797b0df32).

Here is the output from it:

```
    ------------------
    Pre init attributes
    The doc is new, run app once again
    ------------------
    ------------------
    Post init attributes
    { _id: 55a37cc88ff0f55e6ee9be2d,
      name: 'Test 1 - 12:07:88',
      __v: 0,
      ready: true }
    Setting this.oldValues
    ------------------
    ------------------
    Pre save attributes
    { _id: 55a37cc88ff0f55e6ee9be2d,
      name: 'Test 1 - 12:07:16',
      __v: 0,
      ready: false }
    ------------------
    ------------------
    Post save attributes
    { _id: 55a37cc88ff0f55e6ee9be2d,
      name: 'Test 1 - 12:07:16',
      __v: 0,
      ready: false }
    The old attributes (model.oldValues)
    { _id: '55a37cc88ff0f55e6ee9be2d',
      name: 'Test 1 - 12:07:88',
      __v: 0,
      ready: true }
    ------------------
```